# A "looser" word than "proportional" for relating two variables meaning "if x increases, y increases, and if x decreases, y decreases"

Tags: functions, derivatives, terminology

The closest term I can think of or find is "correlated", but that has a bunch of different possible interpretations.

Over the interval $(0, \infty]$, the two variables of each of these functions satisfy the relation that I'm talking about:

[image: different order polynomials graph]

The blue and green lines ($x$, $kx^3$) have pairs of variables that satisfy it over their whole domain.

I also imagine prepending "negatively" to the word just as you can say "negatively correlated" to specify that if one goes up, the other goes down, and vice versa.

Comment: If you think of $y$ as a function of $x$, you can say $y(x)$ is an increasing function of $x$.

Comment: I'd say both functions are increasing and decreasing on the same intervals.  Which if they are continuous implies they have coinciding maxima/minima.

Comment: Oh, if you are just talking about one function, in relation to one input variable the word you are looking for is "monotonic increasing".

Comment: @fleablood, Since OP says $y$ _increases_ as $x$ _increases_, perhaps it's better to say "strictly increasing" rather than "monotone increasing".

Comment: Funny.  for some brain-farty reason I briefly thought monotonic meant strictly increasing as opposed to simply "increasing" which meant never decreasing.  Of course, it is the opposite and you are right.  monotonic increasing means never decreasing whereas strictly increasing means ... strictly increasing.  Bit of a lapse there.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! After some googling: Might we say x and y are "co-monotonic" / "counter-monotonic" as used [here](https://ir.lib.uwo.ca/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=4937&context=etd)? That paper also speaks of "monotonicity" and "lack of monotonicity". Or maybe the "monotone dependence" of x and y as used [here](http://thescipub.com/pdf/10.3844/jmssp.2012.221.228)? I've heard of the term monotonic before, but this stuff is a bit new to me.